# SQLAlchemy: Select DISTINCT ON column by dropping duplicates and retaining the max

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Consider the following Scores table:

```
class Scores(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    time_elapsed = db.Column(db.Integer) # Time spent playing the game in seconds
```

Example Table:

| id | user_id | score | time_elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 75 |
| 2 | 1 | 70 | 190 |
| 3 | 1 | 80 | 97 |
| 4 | 2 | 90 | 32 |
| 5 | 2 | 45 | 59 |

I want to select the maximum scores of all individual users (by user_id).

The result would be:

| id | user_id | score | time_elapsed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 75 |
| 4 | 2 | 90 | 32 |

Because the player with user id 1 has a top score of 100 and the player with user id 2 has a top score of 90.

The method that I have within the Scores class looks like this:

```
    @classmethod
    def get_top_scores(cls):
        results = db.session.query(func.max(cls.score),
                                   cls.user_id,
                                   cls.id,
                                   cls.time_elapsed) \
            .group_by(cls.user_id) \
            .all()
        keys = ['score', 'user_id', 'id', 'time_elapsed']

        return [{i: j for i, j in zip(keys, row)} for row in results]
```

This result gets returned by an API, thus the list comprehension and nested dictionary comprehension to get the expected format of the output, which looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "score": 100,
        "user_id": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "time_elapsed": 75
    },
    {
        "score": 90,
        "user_id": 2,
        "id": 4,
        "time_elapsed": 32
    },
]
```

This appears to be working as expected but is there an alternative/better way to do this?

Seems awfully complex for something pretty straightforward -- the requirement is to drop duplicates on user_id and retain the row with the max score!

Answer (score 0):

`order_by` makes it little bit easy.

```
results = db.session.query(cls.scores).order_by(asc(cls.scores.user_id).desc(cls.scores.score)).group_by(cls.scores.user_id).all()
```